# How to build a proper pkg-file that installs an app-bundle on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, pkg

I know this question was discussed many times before, but the proposed `buildkg`-commands don't work for me on Mac OS Monterey. Here are two commands I tried:

```sh
sudo pkgbuild --install-location /Applications/MyApp.app --component $HOME/Build/MyApp.app $HOME/MyApp.pkg
```

```sh
sudo pkgbuild --install-location /Applications --root $HOME/Build $HOME/MyApp.pkg
```

For both commands I get an empty app-bundle in `/Applications` after installation and for some reason (possibly related to APFS copy-on-write feature?) the source app-bundle (used when building the package) gets empty too.

Comment: I think the first one should just have`--install-location /Applications`, not `--install-location /Applications/MyApp.app`.

Comment: Then it doesn't put anything into /Applications, but the source app-bundle gets empty as before.

Comment: You might take a look at http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html, a pretty good Cocoa app from creating packages.